# A microphone for video streaming from a tennis court

Tags: microphone, sport

Can some one Please advise on which microphone to use to record sound for live video streaming from a tennis court, both indoor courts and outdoor courts.

And I will also appreciate any advise on where to locate the mic.

Thank you

Comment: What is your budget? What other sound gear do you have? Did you also check this: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/13337/place-microphones-for-live-sports-broadcasting?rq=1. You will realistically need more than one mic to get anything near the expected quality of broadcast sound for this type of event.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Do_tennis_players_have_a_microphone_on_them_while_playing